# Targeting DOM elements inside Angular component ngAfterViewInit returns empty nodeList

Tags: angular

So, I have a service and inside it I have methods that return promises. Inside my `component.ts` file I am injecting the service and then trying to call its methods inside a `Promise.all([])` because I need all the results from the service before I can render the view.

The way I do that is via an `*ngIf` directive on the container element of the template which checks whether the results from the service have all been returned (via a variable called `pageReady`) and then renders the template.

My component.ts file...

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './services/myservice.service';

@Component({...})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public pageReady: Promise<boolean>;
    public items;
    public items2;
    public nodelist;

    constructor( private service: MyService, private el: ElementRef ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.fetchData();
    }

    /* This right here is my problem */
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.nodelist = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.items figure');
      console.log(this.nodelist);
    }

    private getFirstItem() {
      return this.service.serviceMethodOne(); /* Returns promise */
    }

    private getSecondItem() {
      return this.service.serviceMethodTwo(); /* Returns promise */
    }

    private async fetchData() {
       return await Promise.all([this.getFirstItem(), this.getSecondItem()]).then(res => {
          // Assign returned values to class variables that will be used in the template
          this.items = res[0];
          this.items2 = res[1];

          this.pageReady = Promise.resolve(true);  
       });
    }
}
```

Template file...

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="pageReady | async ; else loading">
   <section class="items">
      <figure *ngFor="let item of items">
         <img src="{{ item.path }}" alt="{{ item.title }}">
      </figure>
   </section>

   <section class="items2">
      <div class="item2" *ngFor="let item2 of items2">
         <p>{{ item2.name }}</p>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

I need to manipulate the DOM elements targeted inside `ngAfterViewinit` but it returns an empty nodeList. Everything else works fine, I get all the data back and the `<ng-template>Loading</ng-template>` displays then disappears as expected. 
I need to know how I can target those DOM elements successfully.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.items figure');
      console.log(this.nodelist); /* Returns an empty nodeList */
    }

Comment: If you're manipulating DOM elements from your component, then you're doing it wrong. Don't do that. Modify the model, and the template will adapt. What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you just use a boolean for pageReady?

Comment: pageReady being a boolean makes no difference. The nodeList is still empty.

Comment: Yes, this is unrelated. It's just needlessly complicated to use a Promise as a boolean. Again, using DOM manipulation in components is wrong, and goes against the whole design principles of Angular. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a gallery component with slider images and thumbnails that's why I need to access and manipulate DOM elements. How would you suggest I go about it?

Comment: By writing/using a dedicated slider component widget. I'm not exactly sure what such a component should do. But see ng-bootstrap's accordion component, for example (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples), and its source code (https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.ts). It doesn't have any DOM manipulation. The template is used to bind events.

Comment: I get the idea. I'l browse the web to find a carousel that fits my needs instead of implementing one myself. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem! My problem was, that the component got initialised but the data did not arrive from the backend and was not loaded into the DOM yet. I used ```setTimeout``` to solve the problem: ```this.service.getData.subscribe({complete: ()=> {setTimeout(){// your code}}})```